# How to embed image or picture in ONLY ONE jupyter notebook file using jupyter/ipython internal magic function?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython, jupyter

if there is a Jupyter/IPython magic(%) function to complete following task:
i have made the function to insert image/picture in ONLY ONE Jupyter Notebook file;

```
def image_embed(filename, width, height=0):
    from IPython.display import Image
    import os,sys,base64
    img = Image(filename=filename, embed=True, unconfined=True, retina=False)
    html_template = '<img width="%s" %s src="data:image/%s;base64,%s">'
    height_str = ('height="%s"'%(height,)) if height else ''
    img_b64str = base64.b64encode(img.data).decode()
    img_html = html_template % (width, height_str, img.format, img_b64str)
    return img_html

#example:
print(image_embed("/Users/abaelhe/Desktop/Jupyter_AI.png", 600, 100))
```

Comment: What do you mean by only one file, you return html with the function, we have no idea what you do with the returned html and where you intend to use it, however your definition of "only one" is very unclear, do you mean you want to use it just in one single notebook? or do you mean you have defined the function in one notebook and want to use it in others? (would make more sense)

Comment: to save all materials in ONE file, includes notebook/images/...